# I want to know whether my ISP sharing my internet connection with others

Tags: networking, isp, broadband, dsl

Recently my ISP changed how they provide internet access. It used to be a dedicated IP address and a direct connection based on computer name and MAC address, so there was no way anyone else could use my internet connection. They have changed that, and given me a username and password on a DSL connection. I am now getting slow speed during day. There is no way to change the password. I know they are using my connection, but I need proof. They are probably giving my user info to others, and making money during the daytime.

Is there any way I can find out which computers are connected to my network and what they are doing?

Also, is there way I can block anyone from accessing the connection after I log in?

Comment: “based on computer name and mac address, so there was no way anyone could use my internet” – Yeah, no. This is so incredibly easy to circumvent it might as well be no protection at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, your ISP shares the Internet connection among all their users, there is no problem with that, you only must be sure that they are providing you the services you have signed in your contract with them.

Note that DSL connection based on username and password does not mean that your Internet connection is being shared with other users, it is supposed that every user has their own assigned bandwidth.

If you are suspecting about somebody is also using your connection (i.e. via wifi), you should check your network device in order to find any other possible connection that you don't recognize, but without more details about how are you connecting I cannot tell you how to check it.

Comment: Exactly, DSL means I should get the bandwidth I paid for but I'm getting 20% bandwidth that I'm paying for during day. Just like when I'm using it on my laptop and then connect my mobile and get a slow speed that i can browse with. These people are armature, thief and I know them. Just want some prove.

Its a broadband wired connection. Comes thru fiber optic cable .

Comment: Have you tried to do a speed test when you have only one device connected? Also, there are some routers in which you can check the actual bandwidth that is provided by the ISP, I suggest you to check your sync speed on that way.

Comment: No router involved. I use converter to directly connect to my Ethernet port. And I checked everything. There's 2 reason my internet could be slow 
1. The whole area getting slow speed(which isn't, I checked).
2. They gave someone else my ID and Pass. Cause I sleep during most days .
Now tell me is there's any way I can get prove.

Comment: There's always a router. The internet doesn't work without one. Your issue would appear to be **contention ratio** - too many people on the same street all trying to use at the same time what is a shared resource. Your ISP's entire business model is based on how many users they can get on one share. No-one is "stealing" your bandwidth, they're all suffering the same contention issues. You need to complain to your ISP & get them to change their ratio in your area... but don't expect them to ever admit they've over-subscribed; it just won't happen.

Answer (score -2):

There is in *indirect* way to detect internet connection sharing: You can use tools like [Loggger](http://loggger.com/) to periodically measure your available bandwidth/internet download speed. This way you know if anything in your connection has changed (= shared with more users).

Comment: Downvoters, please explain what is wrong with this idea

Comment: The concept seems to be wrong. Decreased stored doesn't necessarily mean that somebody else is connected to your network. Also,  if somebody else is connected that doesn't necessarily cause decreased speed.